# Return sorted fields from single Firestore document

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore allows you to sort *documents* when querying *collections* (e.g., `citiesRef.orderBy("name")`): https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

However, is there a way to sort a document's fields?

For instance, I have the following data model in Firestore:

```
exampleCollection: {
    documentId: {
        field1: {sortOnMe: 1, foo: bar},
        field2: {sortOnMe: 2, foo: bar},
        field3: {sortOnMe: 3, foo: bar}
    }
}
```

And I am currently returning all fields in a given document like so:

```
exampleCollection.doc(documentId)
                 .valueChanges()
                 .subscribe((response) => { 
                     // response = {
                     //     field2: {sortOnMe: 2, foo: bar},
                     //     field3: {sortOnMe: 3, foo: bar},
                     //     field1: {sortOnMe: 1, foo: bar}
                     // }
                  });
```

This works well and is responsive to changes. However, the order in which the `exampleData` is unpredictable, and can change when new fields are added. Is there a way to order the fields returned from the query above based on some nested field in them, such as `sortOnMe`?

If not, is it better to have an additional layer of collections in each document that can then be sorted? Coming from Firebase I'm hesitant to nest too deeply, but that may not be as much of a problem in Firestore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data inside a document is JSON. There is no way to control the order of fields in a JSON object. You'll have to order it in your JavaScript code.

E.g.

```js
var json = {
     field2: {sortOnMe: 2, foo: 'bar'},
     field3: {sortOnMe: 3, foo: 'bar'},
     field1: {sortOnMe: 1, foo: 'bar'}
};

var keys = Object.keys(json);
keys.sort((a,b) => json[a].sortOnMe - json[b].sortOnMe);

var sorted = keys.map(key => json[key]);

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 2):

`orderBy` orders the documents, not the fields within the documents.  In your example, you have fetched one document.  You have a couple of options:

1. Fetch the document and order the fields in your client
2. Create a sub-collection and fetch all documents in the sub-collection, ordered by your the value in your field.